# Is there a reason why True and False are still modifiable in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, constants

Built-in constants `True` and `False` are [unmodifiable in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/constants.html) since at least 3.3:

> The false value of the bool type. Assignments to `False` are illegal and
>   raise a `SyntaxError`.
>
> The true value of the bool type. Assignments to `True` are illegal and
>   raise a `SyntaxError`.

However, in python 2.7, the code `True = 0` executes without any exceptions. It seems these restrictions should have been ported to 2.x long ago, but they haven't.

The only reason I can think of is compatibility with existing code base. Do you know any case when the existing software is deliberately modifying `True` or `False`? If not, what other reasons might there be?

Comment: The duplicate doesn't seem to answer why it *wasn't backported*. Granted, the title doesn't actually mirror the question body.

Comment: "Do you know any case when the existing software is deliberately modifying True or False?" - people used to assign `True=1` and `False=0` (or `true=1`, or `TRUE=1`...) back when Python didn't actually have bools, and they needed to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: I see your point. Correct me if I'm wrong but python 2.2 introduced a whole new keyword `yield` (PEP 255), which broke compatibility for those who had used `yield` as a variable. Don't see any difference here.

Comment: @Free I'm pretty sure that instances of people using `yield` are way less than people defining a pretty universal constant like `True` and `False`.

Comment: I'm sure it was when `True` and `False` were introduced in the language (which version was it, by the way?). Is it still actual today, in 2017?

Comment: If Python 2 only had to be compatible with code written in 2017, we could change a lot of things.

Answer (score 6):

As Guido states in [the story of `None`, `True` and `False`](http://python-history.blogspot.gr/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html), context matters in the case of not making `True` and `False` keywords in the first place. When bool was introduced (with PEP 285 in Python 2.3) it couldn't of been made a keyword because a lot of code in existence already defined it in one way or another:

> The situation for `True`/`False` is a little different. They weren't always part of the language, and *many people had invented their own convention*. People would define constants named true and false, True and False, or TRUE and FALSE, and use those consistently throughout their code. I don't recall which spelling was most popular, but *when we introduced True and False into the language, **we definitely did not want to break any packages** that were defining their own `True` and `False` constants.*

and continues to state in a later paragraph:

> So, essentially our hand was forced in this case, and we had to introduce `True` and `False` as built-in constants, not as keywords. But over time, code defining its own versions of `True` and `False` (by whichever name) became more and more frowned upon, and by the time Python 3 came around, when we looked at opportunities for cleaning up the language, *we found that it was logical to make `True` and `False` keywords, by analogy to `None`*.

You correctly assume that:

> The only reason I can think of is compatibility with existing code base.

And, indeed, this is the case. The need to keep backwards-compatibility between versions of Python 2 is why `True` and `False` aren't keywords there.

Python 3 is different in that *it introduced a number of backwards incompatible changes* in an effort to clean the language up, the awkward re-assigning to `True` and `False` can no longer be done, *thankfully*.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really that `True` and `False` can be modified, so much as that `True` and `False` can be names, and if they are names, those names will shadow the names in `builtin`. That is `True` and `False` are not handled by the parser as special symbols, but appear to be looked up in the current local and global binding scope:

```
>>> True = 'mumble'
>>> True
'mumble'
>>> bool(True)
True
>>> bool(True) == True # "mumble" == True
False
>>> bool(True) == bool(True)
True
```

So, it's a language design choice about how to interact with the symbols.